# Is there a way to have a system generated report of list of DBA in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm an auditor, and I want to ask if there is a list of system generated report of DBA users in SQL Server? Per my audit client, there is no way to generate it.

However, I'm thinking that this is a data also in which you can just generate to the SQL Server databases. I just want to validate that the list of DBAs is restricted to DBA of our company for legitimate business need and security purpose.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: There are a million questions on how to query sql schemas etc on this site, so I'd vote that it belongs here. Question is about how to query system tables or information_schema to find permissions. Need to specify what exact permissions you define as "DBA" though as its a lot more granular these days.

Comment: Although not completely relevant for StackOverflow, I thought I would try expand your thinking on this. Firstly, from an Audit perspective, what are you referring to when saying "A list of DBA". A SQL Server instance can have `sysadmin` users which essentially have access to everything. A separate group of users could have `dbo` permissions / similar on a database and be able to modify any data within that database. Both could sneakily post a fraudulent general ledger entry and launder money out of your ERP system as they both have access. If you could expand your question, that would be great

Comment: Adding onto @Matt's sentiment - what types of operations/permissins are you trying to figure out the set of people who have access to do them? Modify schema? Modify the data? *See* the data? While admins can do all of those things, there are lower privileges that also confer those abilities. So identifying admins may be *necessary* but not *sufficient*.